# pass password from .env on command to mysql inside docker

Tags: mysql, bash, docker, environment-variables, exec

I basically know nothing about docker. And not that much more about bash neither. So:

There's a command in the README of a Laravel project i'm working on, that shows how to fill some data on local MySQL docker image, by sending a queries from a file located in the HOST.

```
docker exec -i {image} mysql -uroot -p{password} {database} < location/of/file.sql
```

What i want to do is "hide" the password from README, and make it read from `.env` file

So, i want to do something like this:

```
docker exec --env-file=.env -i {image} mysql -uroot -p$DB_PASSWORD {database} < location/of/file.sql
```

I've tested that `docker ... printenv` does show the variables from the file. But *echoing* one of then outputs a blank line: `docker ... echo $DB_PASSWORD` and running MySQL command using it, gets me "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'"

I've tried run the MySQL command "directly": `docker ... mysql ... < file.sql` and also "indirectly": `docker bash -c "mysql ..." < file.sql`.

Comment: You can set the password in the env variable `MYSQL_PWD`.

Comment: setting `MYSQL_PWD` manually on my `.env` worked. But i need to keep `DB_PASSWORD`. 'Composing' `MYSQL_PWD="${DB_PASSWORD}"` denied me access, thought recognized `(using password: YES)`.

Comment: There's no way to force the command to use the `DB_PASSWORD` variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should prevent your shell from expanding the local variables (by single-quoting, or by escaping `$`)

This should be passed to containers shell and expanded there:

```bash
docker exec --env-file=.env -i {image} bash -c 'mysql -uroot -p$DB_PASSWORD {database}' < location/of/file.sql
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the answer. It wasn't kite there.

For some reason, escaping just the password command, as in the example, gives acces denied.
For proper solve, i had to `exec ... bash -c 'mysql ...' < location/of/file.sql`. So password is expanded inside the container, and still reading sql file from HOST

Comment: I've edited yout answer, to show the format that worked as expected, and set it as accepted the one.

Answer (score 0):

It could possibly be two cases.

1. Check the key name in your env file and the docker run command
2. Check the path of the env file you are mapping to.

Comment: both are correct. and as stated, i can confirm the command `printenv` (inside image) show the variables, but `echo` doesn't print it's value out